# Jenkins: Cobertura plugin cannot find coverage report

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage

Here are my build logs. I am absolutely baffled and would appreciate any help.
I'm using `cobertura` plugin version `1.16`.

```
+ ls
Dockerfile
Jenkinsfile
README.md
babel.config.js
coverage
dev-server.sh
jenkins-agent.yaml
jest.config.ts
package-lock.json
package.json
src
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
+ ls ./coverage
cobertura-coverage.xml
+ pwd
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/api_PR-8
+ cat ./coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE coverage SYSTEM "http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/xml/coverage-04.dtd">
<coverage lines-valid="129" lines-covered="46" line-rate="0.3566" branches-valid="1" branches-covered="1" branch-rate="1" timestamp="1609204078913" complexity="0" version="0.1">
  <sources>
    <source>/app</source>
  </sources>
  <packages>
    ...
  </packages>
</coverage>
[Pipeline] cobertura
[Cobertura] Publishing Cobertura coverage report...

[Cobertura] No coverage results were found using the pattern './coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml' relative to '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/api_PR-8'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you generate the XML report(s) for Cobertura?
```

I have also tried using the pattern `'coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml'` as well, and I got the same error.

This is the relevant section of my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    docker build . --target test
                    DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . -o ./coverage --target coverage
                    ls
                    ls ./coverage
                    pwd
                    cat ./coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml
                '''
                cobertura(coberturaReportFile: './coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml')
            }
        }
```

## Update 1

This is interesting... I tried changing the value of `coberturaReportFile` to `coverage/*.xml`, and the build produced the following error:

```
[Pipeline] cobertura
[Cobertura] Publishing Cobertura coverage report...

FATAL: Unable to find coverage results
java.io.IOException: IO error scanning directory '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/api_PR-8/coverage'
    at hudson.FilePath.glob(FilePath.java:1975)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$3400(FilePath.java:212)
    at hudson.FilePath$ListGlob.invoke(FilePath.java:1949)
    at hudson.FilePath$ListGlob.invoke(FilePath.java:1937)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1076)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1059)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1935)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1919)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1904)
    at hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher$ParseReportCallable.invoke(CoberturaPublisher.java:896)
    at hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher$ParseReportCallable.invoke(CoberturaPublisher.java:885)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3122)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from 10.0.4.46/10.0.4.46:49386
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1800)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:357)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:1001)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1070)
        at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1059)
        at hudson.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaPublisher.perform(CoberturaPublisher.java:548)
        at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:99)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:69)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

So maybe there was a try-catch in the Cobertura plugin code that was silencing this IO error.

It's not clear to me why this IO error is occurring or what it means. The workspace is created fresh for every build.

## Update 2

I also tried using the pattern `**/cobertura-coverage.xml`, but got the same error as in my initial post.

```
[Cobertura] Publishing Cobertura coverage report...

[Cobertura] No coverage results were found using the pattern '**/cobertura-coverage.xml' relative to '/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/api_PR-8'.  Did you enter a pattern relative to the correct directory?  Did you generate the XML report(s) for Cobertura?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a file ownership problem. Putting `ls -l` in my pipeline script revealed that the `coverage/` directory and `coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml` were being produced with `root:root` ownership, not `1000:1000` (AKA `jenkins:jenkins`). That's why cobertura skipped over the directory or failed to read from it.

```
+ ls -alh
total 500K   
drwxr-xr-x    5 1000     1000        4.0K Dec 29 02:59 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 1000     1000        4.0K Dec 29 02:58 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000          77 Dec 29 02:58 .dockerignore
drwxr-xr-x    8 1000     1000        4.0K Dec 29 02:59 .git
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000          47 Dec 29 02:58 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000         353 Dec 29 02:58 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000        1.5K Dec 29 02:58 Jenkinsfile
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000         877 Dec 29 02:58 README.md
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000         145 Dec 29 02:58 babel.config.js
drwx------    2 root     root        4.0K Dec 29 02:59 coverage
-rwxr-xr-x    1 1000     1000         316 Dec 29 02:58 dev-server.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000         289 Dec 29 02:58 jenkins-agent.yaml
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000        6.5K Dec 29 02:58 jest.config.ts
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000      420.5K Dec 29 02:58 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000        1.0K Dec 29 02:58 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    9 1000     1000        4.0K Dec 29 02:58 src
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000        5.4K Dec 29 02:58 tsconfig.json
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000         472 Dec 29 02:58 webpack.config.js
```

To fix it, I changed the ownership on the directory before running `cobertura`. Here's my final solution:

```
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    docker build . --target test
                    DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build . -o ./coverage --target coverage
                    chown -R 1000:1000 ./coverage
                '''
                cobertura(coberturaReportFile: 'coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml')
            }
        }
```